# Quickbooks - Trouble with QODBC SQL

Tags: quickbooks, qodbc

I'm having problems when I try to insert invoice.
I run these queries in the VB Demo app and in both have errors.

Any idea?

**Query 1**

```
insert into invoiceline
(CustomerRefFullName,RefNumber,InvoiceLineSerialNumber,InvoiceLineDesc,FQSaveToCache)
values
('Esteban Inc.','98908','1','line 1',1)
---
insert into invoice
(CustomerRefFullName,ARAccountRefListID,TemplateRefFullName,RefNumber,TermsRefFullName,TxnDate,DueDate,
"BillAddressAddr1", "BillAddressAddr2", "BillAddressAddr3", "BillAddressCity", "BillAddressState", "BillAddressPostalCode", "BillAddressCountry",
"CustomerSalesTaxCodeRefFullName", "ItemSalesTaxRefFullName","IsPending","IsToBePrinted")
values
('Esteban Inc.','80000029-1478460828' ,'Time & Expense Invoice','98908','Net 30',{d'2016-10-31'},{d'2016-11-30'},
'Esteban Inc.','Project: TEST','Street 0001 - Dpto H','Rosario', 'Santa Fe', '2000','Argentina',
'Non','NY - Monroe County',0,1)
```

Error

[image]

**Query 2**

```
INSERT INTO "InvoiceLine" ("InvoiceLineItemRefListID", "InvoiceLineSalesTaxCodeRefListID",
"InvoiceLineType", "InvoiceLineQuantity", 
"InvoiceLineRate", "InvoiceLineAmount", 
"InvoiceLineDesc", 
"InvoiceLineClassRefListID", "FQSaveToCache") 
VALUES (null,'80000002-1478214656', 
'Item', 0.75,
125, 93.75,
'10/26/2016 - Regular - Dario Diaz (0.75 hours) // Q4 2016 Retainer  - October Retainer Work - Reviewing issue with pdf''s media type with Ale, testing in dev.', 
'80000001-1478457400', 1)

INSERT INTO "Invoice" ("CustomerRefListID", "ARAccountRefListID", "TemplateRefListID", 
"TxnDate" ,"RefNumber", "BillAddressAddr1", 
"BillAddressAddr2", "BillAddressAddr3", "BillAddressCity", 
"BillAddressState", "BillAddressPostalCode", "BillAddressCountry", 
"IsPending", "IsToBePrinted", "TermsRefListID", 
"DueDate", "CustomerSalesTaxCodeRefListID") 
VALUES ('80000002-1478457181', '80000029-1478460828', '8000000B-1478214656',
{d'2016-08-23'}, '102400', 'Some Client', 
'Project: Some Client - Q4 2016 Retainer', '190A Street', 'Rochester',
'NY', '14625', 'USA', 
0, 1, '80000006-1478214663', 
{d'2016-11-30'}, '80000001-1478214656')
```

Error

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Esteban.-

Comment: Are you trying to create an invoiceline without an item ?    I noticed you have specified InvoiceLineSalesTaxCodeRefListID and item type = Item but you did not specified the InvoiceLineItemRefListID.    Are you able to create the same record via QuickBooks Application (GUI). ?

Comment: Query 1 : I think you might NOT have Advanced inventory enabled in your QuickBooks. As you are SerialNumber in your SQL statement advance inventory is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query 1 : I think you might NOT have Advanced inventory enabled in your QuickBooks. As you are SerialNumber in your SQL statement advance inventory is required.

Query 2 :From the query, I noticed that you are inserting null value in InvoiceLineItemRefListID field. You need to insert a valid value in InvoiceLineItemRefListID field.

Please refer below mentioned article for creating Invoice using QODBC:
http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2389/0/how-to-create-invoices-using-qodbc

-- 
Rajendra Dewani

Support Supervisor, QODBC & QODBC-POS

FLEXquarters.com Limited